# An efficient way to multiply two dataframes based on a condition on a certain column

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I would like to multiply two dataframes df1 and df2, based on a condition and in an efficient way.

df1:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['user_id', 'gender', 'value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3'], data = [[112,0,50,60,70], [73,10,20,40,55],[61, 0, 15, 30, 45]])

    user_id   gender   value_1   value_2   value_3
0   112       0         50         60        70
1   73        10        20         40        55
2   61        0         15         30        45
```

df2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['gender', 'value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3'], data = [[2, 3, 5, 0], [4, 6, 7, 10]])

          value_1    value_2    value_3    gender
0         2          3          5          0
1         4          6          7          10
```

I would like to multiply the value_1, value_2, value_3 columns of df1 by df2 where the gender column matches in both dataframes.
I've done this in the following way and it works fine:

```
val_cols = ['value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3']
df1.loc[df1.gender==0, val_cols] *= df2[df2.gender==0][val_cols].values[0].tolist()
df1.loc[df1.gender==10, val_cols] *= df2[df2.gender==10][val_cols].values[0].tolist()
```

But this is only applicable if the gender column has only a few values, in this case it can only be 0 and 10. But what if there was more distinct values for gender?
**Is there a better way to do this in case the gender values and accordingly the number of records in the df2 is higher?**
PS: My real dataframes are very large so I can't use apply or map functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `.set_index()` to `gender` on both dataframes and then do `df.mul()`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['user_id', 'gender', 'value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3'], data = [[112,0,50,60,70], [73,10,20,40,55],[61, 0, 15, 30, 45]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3', 'gender'], data = [[2, 3, 5, 0], [4, 6, 7, 10]])

df1 = df1.set_index(['gender', 'user_id'])
df2 = df2.set_index('gender')

out = df1.mul(df2, level=0)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
                value_1  value_2  value_3
gender user_id                           
0      112          100      180      350
10     73            80      240      385
0      61            30       90      225
```